# How to solve the error string indices must be integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

TypeError: string indices must be integers. 
For example: 20 is applicable but not 3550.

```
i=0
for key in dict1:
       for keys in dict2:
           if (dict1[key]['TITLE']==dict2[keys]['TITLE']):
               if pd.isna(d1.loc[i,'DB']) is True: 
                   d1.iloc[i]=dict2[keys]
    i+=1
```

The dict1 and 2 looks like:

```
{'DB': 'A',
 'TITLE': 'Wildlife Biology',
 'ISSN': '0909-6396',
 'e-ISSN': nan,
 'ISBN': nan,
 'e-ISBN': nan}
```

for dict1[key] when key=20

The error pop out when running.

```
if (dict1[key]['TITLE']==dict2[keys]['TITLE']):

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Where does `i` come from?

Comment: i is count1, which is also a 3500+ integer.

Comment: What is `len(dictN)`

Comment: Is dict1 a list of dictionaries? or a dictionary itself?

Comment: @CharlesLandau- len(dict1)is 3680 and len(dict2) is 3817

Comment: @hacker315 - It is a dictionary itself, which contains a lot of nested dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

"TypeError: string indices must be integers" means that one of `dictN` or `dictN[i]` is a string. I would start debugging by investigating the types for each of those.

Your sample data isn't making sense to me because if `dictN` really was a Python dict then `dictN[i]` where `i` was an integer would result in a `KeyError`. If you post more information it could help the community make a better answer.

Comment: Hi! dict1, dict1[i], dict2, dict2[j] are all type dict.

Comment: dict1 contains a total of 3680 dictionaries inside, while dict2 contains a total of 3817 dictionaries inside. They are formed from dataframes.to_dict(orient='index').

Comment: The dictionary example shown above is what dict1[20] looks like, which is also a dictionary itself.